# LibUsbDotNet Bulk Transfer Usb Communication Win32Error

Tags: usb, port, serial-communication, libusbdotnet

We have a vendor-specific device for USB connections.

We used **LibUsbDotNet** Bulk Transfer communication. In the first case, I did **64 byte** data transfer. In the second case I made **1024 byte** data transfer. In case of **64 byte** transfer, there is usually no problem (Problems are rare). In case of **1024 byte** transfer, there is a problem (almost always in ***USB 2.0 port***, also rare in ***USB 3.0 port***).

What causes to this problem?

Comment: Hello, any news about that?

Answer (score 0):

When data is in multiple of 512 bytes, add an extra dummy byte to the data. So if you are transferring 1025 bytes your problem will be solved.